# Is there a way to return specific products for a custom search term?

Tags: magento2, search-terms, elasticsearch

i.e. create a search term like XYZ123

and have it return only items I specify? Like if I am running a promo on specific items and only want to show those items when people search for XYZ123?

Answer (score 0):

the closest answer I have found is on the following article: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/search-synonyms.html

I did try it and it does the job. However, I don't have it quite working with sku. But hopefully, this may help you as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only single item then you can redirect to the product page or if you want to show multiple items then you can redirect to category page or you can create a custom page with some product listing and redirect to this page.

To redirect to a particular page, while a user searches for a particular term, you can use `Redirect URL` attribute of `Search Terms` under `Marketing -> Search Terms -> Select or Add New Search Term`

For more details you can go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/search-terms.html